# Прошу объяснить почему не запускается цикл

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
d = 1
while d > 2:
     p = int (input ("2+1 = "  ))
     if p == 3:
             print ("correct")
             break
     else:
             print ("wrong")
```

Не работает от слова совсем, но понять в чем проблема не получается...
По идее после ответ на вопрос правильный, цикл выключается и выводится слово "correct", а если не неправильный, то пишет "wrong" и цикл начинается сначала.

Comment: Эм. У вас d равно 1 и написано "пока d больше двух делать (то-то)". И как мы войдём в цикл? Мы действительно не можем войти в него, потому что вы задали такое условие.

Answer (score 1):

Поменяй знак на d == 1:, или d < 2:, ну или просто напиши while True без d вообще.